# automatically redirect output to /dev/null

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple script with a lot of output:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
} 2>&1
```

Starting it with `./script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1` silences it.

Can I silence the script from the inside?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question.

Comment: @OrangeDog it's perfectly understandable; it could also phrased "How can I redirect my script's output from inside the script rather than on the command line?"

Comment: @Wildcard it has been edited since I made the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the redirection in your script:

--EDIT-- after Jeff Schaller comment

```
#!/bin/bash
# case 1: if you want to hide all message even errors
{
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
} > /dev/null 2>&1


#!/bin/bash
# case 2: if you want to hide all messages but errors
{
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
} > /dev/null
```

Comment: Note that `2>&1 > /dev/null` assigns stderr to stdout, *then* assigns stdout to /dev/null -- the upshot will be that you'll see stderr messages. If the goal is to 'silence the script', you should rearrange the assignment to: `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `bash` built-in command `exec` is for (although it can perform other actions as well).

Excerpted from `man bash` on a CentOS 6.6 box:

```
   exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
          ...
          If command is not specified, any redirections take effect in the
          current shell, and the return status is 0.  If there is a 
          redirection error, the return status is 1.
```

So what you're looking for is `exec >/dev/null 2>&1`.  You can use a `getopts` wrapper to only silence the script if the `-q` option is passed:

```
#!/bin/bash

getopts :q opt
case $opt in
  q)
    exec >/dev/null 2>&1
    ;;
esac
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```

You don't need the `getopts` wrapper, but it might be nice.  Either way, this is much cleaner than sticking your whole script in curly braces.  You can also use `exec` to append output to a logfile:

```
exec 2>>/var/myscript_errors.log
exec >>/var/myscript_output.log
```

You get the idea.  Very handy tool.